# Why is ROC curve always increasing (or non-decreasing)?

Tags: machine-learning, roc

As far as I understood, we plot the (False positive rate, True positive rate) points for all values of threshold. Why should this curve be increasing always? (or non-decreasing)

Comment: Because both false positive rate and true positive rate are monotonically decreasing functions of the classification threshold.

Comment: [Monotonic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function).

Answer (score 10):

(WLOG) Because no case which is classified as a positive will ever be classified as a negative for any lower threshold.

Answer (score 0):

Let's answer by explaining all the involved topics.

---

**What is a probability threshold?**

Assuming binary classification, your model should return the predicted probability of a given feature $\{x\}$ being associated with the "positive label" $y=1$, that is, $\hat{P}:=\hat{P}\left(y(\{x\}) = 1\right)$. One may then argue which threshold value, $p$, for the predicted probability $\hat{P}$ should be considered for labelling the feature $\{x\}$ with $y=1$. It would be reasonable to consider the threshold to be simply $50\,\%$, that is, associating the result $\hat{P}\ge 0.5$ with the label $y=1$ label and the result $\hat{P}< 0.5$ with $y=0$. On the other hand, it would be also wise to choose the threshold value as the one that gives the best result for some performance metric. The receiver operating characteristic (ROC) curve may be useful for identifying this value.

---

**What is a ROC curve?**

The ROC curve corresponds to the relation between the true positive rate ($\mathrm{TPR}$) and the false positive rate ($\mathrm{FPR}$) at different threshold values. The true positive rate is defined as the ratio between true positives ($\mathrm{TP}$) and actual positives (the sum of true positives ($\mathrm{TP}$) and false negatives ($\mathrm{FN}$)):

$$
\mathrm{TPR}=\frac{\mathrm{TP}}{\mathrm{TP} + \mathrm{FN}}\text{ .}
$$

And the false positive rate ($\mathrm{FPR}$) is defined as the ratio between false positives ($\mathrm{FP}$) and actual negatives (the sum of false positives ($\mathrm{TP}$) and true negatives ($\mathrm{TN}$)):

$$
\mathrm{FPR}=\frac{\mathrm{FP}}{\mathrm{FP} + \mathrm{TN}}\text{ .}
$$

---

**Why can't the ROC curve decrease?**

One may show that the ROC curve cannot decrease, that is, $\mathrm{TPR}_{p=p_i}\ge\mathrm{TPR}_{p=p_{i + 1}}\,\forall\,i$, where $p_i$ is the $i$-th threshold and $p_{i+1}$ is the following lower one. When going from $p_i$ to $p_{i+1}$, cases with predicted probabilities that were lower than the previous threshold, $p_i$, and that are now higher than the current threshold, $p_{i+1}$, were previously negativelly labelled but are now positively labelled. If these cases are truly positive, then, such change would transform false negatives ($\mathrm{FN}$) into true positives ($\mathrm{TP}$), decreasing and increasing their numbers, respectively. If the cases are actually truly negative, then, such change would transform true negatives ($\mathrm{TN}$) into false positives ($\mathrm{FP}$). Well, the first circumstance would make $\mathrm{TPR}$ to increase while the second circumstance would not affect $\mathrm{TPR}$, meaning that $\mathrm{TPR}$ cannot decrease.